# Filter condition like "from now to now+1 year" on a date field in Views

Tags: views, 8

I have a custom entity with (among others) a field defined this way:

```
$fields['datedistribution'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
  ->setLabel(t('Date distribution'))
  ->setSetting('datetime_type', 'date')
  ->setDefaultValue(array(0 => array(
    'default_date_type' => 'now',
    'default_date' => 'now',
  )))
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', array(
    'label' => 'above',
    'weight' => 2,
  ))
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
    'weight' => 2,
  ))
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

The values of this field are stored in the database in YYYY-MM-DD format.
I designed a View on this custom entity displaying (among others) this 'datedistribution' field and I use it as a filter criterion.
I would like to a filter condition like "from now to now+1 year".
The available operators being
[image]

how can I do that?

Comment: i don't think you can, core doesn't offer useful date field filters yet. The answer is for Drupal 7.

Comment: Well, you can if you implement your own plugin, which isn't very complicated, but not in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I can help, if I understand your question correctly.
First you should make sure that when you set the filter up, it's in Select form.
[image: select form]

Then you can select the operator as "is between"
Then you select "Enter a relative date" in the dropdown, and you can put now and now+1 year. Not sure if your date fields have a start and end date...

[image: between]

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the step you're mentioning... I go directly from 'Add filter criteria' (see screen capture http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpN5q.png) to 'Configure filter criterion' (see screen capture in my question)

Comment: Hmm are you not using the Date module for dates? Not sure how to handle if a custom date field sorry.

Answer (score 0):

`NOW()` will not work

I have used this method first fetch date from database then  put date to condition

```
$time = \Drupal::database()->query( "SELECT NOW() as currtime " );
$timere = $time->fetchAll();
```